# Approximate accordance between variables

Tags: spss

I have a dataset with lots of doublettes in it. I'd like to search for an approximate accordance between the variables that are double, because they don't have exactly the same names. I'd like to compare them so I can decide which one I have to delete. The variables are pre- and lastnames that are very similar to each other and differ just in a few letters, or sometimes just a comma or a space. For instance, I have a case with the name "Smith" and the next case is named "Smithh", but the cases are the same person. How can I merge them?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probabilistic record linkage, also known as probabilistic matching. As opposed to deterministic record linkage, as provided by the MATCH FILES command. Probabilistic record linkage is not a standard feature of SPSS, but requires additional software.